# How to update second row in my database using datatable "on change" select option

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I am trying to change status of order using select option. First row of datatable is working fine. But when changing status of second order, it is not working.

Select Option Code:

```
 <select name="status" id="status">status
      <option value="Order Placed">{{$assign->status}}</option>
      <option value="On Way">On Way...</option>
      <option value="Delivered">Delivered...</option>
      <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled...</option>
      <input type="hidden" id="order_id" value="{{ $assign->order->id }}" name="order_id">
</select>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').on('change' ,'select', function() {
        var status = $('#status').val();
        var order_id = $('#order_id').val();
        alert(status);

        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "{{ url ('/admin/abc')}}",
          data: {status: status, order_id: order_id},
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function (response) {
            $('.alert').show();
            $('.alert').html(result.success);
          }
        });
    });

  });
```

Route.php:

```
Route::get('/admin/abc','AdminController@abc')->name('assign.abc');
```

Controller code:

```
public function abc(Request $req){
    DB::table('assigns')->WHERE('id',$req->order_id)->update(['status' => $req->status]);
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you put the `input` type outside of the `select` tag? @Vikas Katariya is correct. Your have to POST your request. Anyway, what I would do is put the `data-id="{{ $assign->order->id }}"` in the `select` element and get the id like that in the jQuery. Always try to minimize you code to make it less buggy. .

Comment: You have multiple select and input box?

Comment: Can you show your blade code ?

Comment: i got it. actually my order_id is always 1. that is why status of second order does not change. i am trying again @DimitriMostrey

Comment: @yasin : yes multiple select and order_id

Answer (score 1):

**Change your route file**

```
Route::post('/admin/abc','AdminController@abc')->name('assign.abc');
```

**Change your jQuery code.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('click','#table_id',function(){
        var status = $('#status').val();
        var order_id = $('#order_id').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '{{ route("assign.abc") }}',
          headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },
          data: {status: status, order_id: order_id},
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function (response) {
            $('.alert').show();
            $('.alert').html(result.success);
          }
        });
    });

  });
```

Comment: check alert status and order_id.can you get value?

Comment: yes i am getting values of status and order both. but when i select order status of second row it always pick values of first row

Comment: i got it. actually my order_id is always 1. that is why status of second order does not change. i am trying again . @vikas

Comment: Ok Great So please select answer and please give upvote this answer thank you @Imran

Comment: Please select this answer Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the selected value of your select input

using

```
$('option:selected',this).val()

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').on('change' ,'select', function() {
        var status = $('option:selected',this).val();
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function abc(Request $req, Assign $assign){
 $data = Assign::find($req->order_id);
        $data->status = $req->status;
        $data->save();
         return response()->json(['success'=>'Saved successfully.']);

}

Try This On your Controller

in Route 
Route::get('/admin/abc','AdminController@abc')->name('assign');

in js

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').on('change' ,'select', function() {
        var status = $('#status').val();
        var order_id = $('#order_id').val();
        alert(status);

        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: 'assign',
          data: {status: status, order_id: order_id},
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function (response) {
            $('.alert').show();
            $('.alert').html(result.success);
          }
        });
    });

  });
```